# Highcharts stacked bar chart hide data labels not to overlap

Tags: highcharts

Please check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/HA5xE/

So, I have stacked bar chart and I want to hide data labels when they don't fit in the area. for Example in Category 8, not to have data label "4" at all.

I saw: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.crop and as I understand it should be done automatically, but for some reason doesn't work.

I tried to calculate series are width (or height) in pixels to control show/hide by formatter function, but I was unable to get bar series width.

```
formatter: function() {
if(this.percentage.toFixed(0)>0)
    return this.percentage.toFixed(0);
else 
    return '';
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

FIXED:

```
formatter: function() {
if(this.point.yBottom - this.point.plotY>13)
    return this.percentage.toFixed(0);
else 
    return '';
}
```

Comment: The crop option is not what you are thinking...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can iterate in each point in each serie, then check width of bar and destroy label if widht is smaller than ie.15px .

http://jsfiddle.net/HA5xE/1/

```
 $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){
        $.each(serie.data,function(j,data){
            if(data.yBottom - data.plotY < 15)
                data.dataLabel.destroy();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Great solution Sebastian; I encountered a small problem with stacked columns however. When bound to the `redraw` event; after toggling the visibility of a series, I was getting the error: `Cannot read property 'namespaceURI' of undefined`. A small workaround I discovered is to `hide()` instead of `destroy()`.

Comment: Have you any live demo ?

Comment: This is not working on exporting to PNG/JPEG.
Can you have same type of the solution I can apply when exporting ?

Comment: You need to move loop from callback, into chart / events / load. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HA5xE/20/

Comment: This should be built in. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @SebastianBochan - I am getting some weird values from `yBottom` and `plotY`. What exactly are those two points supposed to be on the graph? (For example.. lower left corner of a graph.. or the bottom coordinate..etc)

Comment: The plotY is value of top edge (in pixels), but the yBottom is lower edge (in pixels).